# Add different styling to each MYSQL row displayed

Tags: php, mysql, row

I need to add a different style to each row displayed from mysql. I am displaying last 4 rows and starting from the first row, the styles should be called first, second, third, fourth.

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '
                    <div class="ot-slider-layer first">
                        <a href="articles/'.$row['slug'].'">
                            <strong><i style="background-color: #ed2d00; color: #fff;">'.category_name_by_id($row['category']).'</i>'.$row['title'].'</strong>
                            <img src="images/articles/'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                ';
            }
        } else {
            echo "There is no news";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Add a counter that is incremented in your `while` loop and set your `class` or whatever accordingly. Alternatively you could add like `(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num` into your `SELECT` statement and use that to determine your style class/id/whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work in this scenario:

```php
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            //array of class names for 4 different rows
            $array = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth');
            //counter variable
            $i = 0;  
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '
                    <div class="ot-slider-layer '.$array[$i].'">
                        <a href="articles/'.$row['slug'].'">
                            <strong><i style="background-color: #ed2d00; color: #fff;">'.category_name_by_id($row['category']).'</i>'.$row['title'].'</strong>
                            <img src="images/articles/'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                ';
                //increment counter variable for each row loop
                ++$i;
            }
        } else {
            echo "There is no news";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this but upon trying it, it only displays the first array value on each row not the others

Comment: Ok, fixed it.  $i = 0;  should be outside the loop

Comment: are you sure you copied it exactly? particularly the "++$i;" part inside the end of the while loop - that's what makes the $i go from 0 to 1 to 2, etc. in order for the array key to be correct.  I just tried a version in my environment and it printed out as expected

Comment: I did, as i mentioned above, it worked when i moved the $i = 0; outside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS for this. have a look the `:nth-child`-selector.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done most easily in CSS without the need for server-side calculations. Your question wasn't clear if you were looking to alternate styles every 4 rows, or just style the last 4. But either can be done with CSS:

**Alternating**: using the [`:nth-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```css
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-child(4n+1) { background: #00ffff50; }
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-child(4n+2) { background: #0000ff50; }
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-child(4n+3) { background: #00000050; }
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-child(4n+4) { background: #ff000050; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">First</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Second</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Third</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Fourth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Fifth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Sixth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Seventh</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Eighth</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Last 4 only:** using the [`nth-last-child` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

```css
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-last-child(4) { background: #00ffff50; }
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-last-child(3) { background: #0000ff50; }
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-last-child(2) { background: #00000050; }
div.ot-slider-layer:nth-last-child(1) { background: #ff000050; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">First</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Second</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Third</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Fourth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Fifth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Sixth</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Seventh</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-slider-layer">
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326081/add-different-styling-to-each-mysql-row-displayed">Eighth</a>
    </div>
</div>
```